# Not able find Compare attribute in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not able to find Compare attribute in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM.
Is this because of me using the ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM? if yes then which version i have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very possible, yes. It didn't exist in MVC 2, but MVC 3 has it (tested it). Try using the latest release of MVC 3 (thus, not the RTM).

If at that point you're still not able to find it, something else is wrong.